# Magento Import "please wait" -> import done without notification

Tags: mysql, magento, import

I hope you can help me with my huge issue.

I tried to setup **magento shop** with **50-60.000 SKUs**. I create a script for **excel** to *convert data into csv*.

It all works well but if i reach a huge number of SKU's - import freeze with "`Please Wait`" and nothing happens. There is no "`successfully`" message after the import. But all products are visible in the back-end. All the data i imported is correctly present in the back-end.

I don't get any response from **html or ajax**, only freeze at "`please wait`". in my experiences, i see the products only when getting "`success`"-message at the end.

It is also **unnormal** that after import no message appears that i had to reindex magento.

Server timeout and other settings are not the problem. After installing new DB, i can import **2.000 skus (configurable) + 15.000 skus (simple)** at once without problems. *The problem appears after a certain amount of SKU's at database.*

I also tried to increase **php memory limit** - without success. I really hope you can help me with your ideas.

Thanks guys!

---

**EDIT**

I try firebug for identify the problem.

i get following response:

Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 268435456 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 8388608 bytes ) in /usr/www/users/sinusi/_duplicateshop/app/code/core/Mage/CatalogInventory/Model/Stock/Status.php on line 489

can you help me?

- set up php memory limit to 2000mb but same error

==============
SOLVED!
problem was the memory_limit -> i set up on backend of hosting service
but there was a lower value at the .htaccess

Thanks so far guys!

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't seem you have allocated 2000mb as it says `Allowed memory size of 268435456 bytes exhausted` (which is 256mb).

For Magento you better set the `memory limit` to 1024mb. Don't forget you need to *restart the server* after any changes made in the configuration files. If the error persists try to increase also these values in your php.ini file:

```
max_input_time
max_execution_time
```

If still the error persists install a debugger ([xdebug](http://xdebug.org/docs/install)) and see if you have a memory leakage somewhere.

In general if possible use dataflow import which consumes much less memory (importing row-by-row) takes lot longer though.